# How to split name using ionic 3

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have one variable which I store my full name and I want to break my name.

```
let fullname ="Praveen Tripathi";
```

I want to this type :-

```
let firstname ="Praveen";
let lastname = "Tripathi";
```

Comment: See [split](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/scripting/javascript/reference/split-method-string-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use split function :-

```
let fullname ="Praveen Tripathi";
let names = fullname.split(" ");
let firstName = names[0];
let lastName = names[1];
```

if your name is more than 2 names you can use this code :-

```
let fullname ="Praveen Tripathi James";
let names = fullname.split(" ");
let firstName = names[0];
let lastName = names[(names.length -1)];
```

Comment: Thank you. It's work for me.